# Is there a way to trigger a manually trigger events in Java Unit Testing

Tags: java, swing, unit-testing

I need to trigger manual event for a ListSelectionListener within my unit test. Is there a way to do this or any workaround to test code inside triggered code?

```
private ListSelectionListener getLeftListSelectionListner()
{
  return e -> {
    if (!leftSelector.getSelectedValueList().isEmpty())
    {
      rightSelector.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
      getAddBtn().setEnabled(true);
    }
    else
    {
      getAddBtn().setEnabled(false);
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Create a `ListSelectionEvent` and pass it to `valueChanged`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Maurice Perry I have figured out an unit test for this situation.

```
  @Test
  public void testGetRightListSelectionListner()
  {
    MultipleSelectionEditor multipleSelectionEditor = new MultipleSelectionEditor();
    ListSelectionEvent listSelectionEvent = mock(ListSelectionEvent.class);

    multipleSelectionEditor.getLeftListSelectionListner().valueChanged(listSelectionEvent);

  }
```

In this case I have mocked `ListSelectionEvent`  and called `valueChanged` with that mocked event